# Can I convert from detectron2 model to tflite model and use it in Android studio?

Tags: tflite

There is a library called d2go, but I have already finished learning with detectron2.
So I converted the format of the model in this order.

pth -> onnx -> pb -> tflite

It works in the android studio, but no results are available result.

Please give me some advice. Thank u.

Comment: i was tiring to do detectron2 but i was un able to run it in my webcam. so i decided to go with d2go but still having some unsolved bug.. i need to run my custom dataset model in android or webcam. it would be great help if you could give some repository that can help me!